# How to filter in records from one dataset to another?

Tags: t-sql, dataset, ssrs-2008

I am developing an SSRS 2008 report.  I created one dataset to give me the records I want.  I also created a different dataset that determines access based on security profiles of the person running the report.  What I want to do now is join the results of this second dataset with those of the first dataset in T-SQL.  So I would like to perform this join within the T-sql sproc for the first dataset.  How do I do this?  Note that in most cases the results of the second (security) dataset is more than one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both datasets coming from the same database? You can probably wrap this logic in a stored procedure instead.